# Install some parts from Github when calling "install.packages()" in R

Tags: r, github, cran

I'd like to put a package onto CRAN. However, the package currently uses an external C model (ISDA Standard model), which is created under public re-distributable license. However, the CRAN administrator refuses to put the package on CRAN if it contains this C model. So is there anyway to put the package onto CRAN without this C model, and when calling `install.packages("my.package")`, it can automatically download the C model from github.com/my_github?

For now, I wrote the following code in `zzz.R`:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    if ( ! "Github_pkg" %in% (all.available = TRUE)){
        devtools::install_github("myGithub/Github_pkg")
    }
}
```

Is this okay if I submit to CRAN? Or should I use `drat` package by Dirk? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

You can look into my [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) package to create your own repository on GitHub.  I use that for example to host the [Rblpapi](https://github.com/armstrtw/Rblpapi) package I contribute to (and which relies on a [library from Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/)) in [this ghrr repository built using drat](http://ghrr.github.io/drat/).

This all works. CRAN has even accepted a package which used the [ghrr drat repo](http://ghrr.github.io/drat/) as an external repository (but since removed that package for another reason).

You still need to organize your "primary" package on CRAN in such a way that the "secondary" package is only a "Suggests:" as actual dependencies must be on CRAN too.  But at least this gives you a way to automate these processes.

Comment: I will submit to CRAN these two weeks, and I have a question. For now, I didn't use `drat` but rather wrote the following code in `zzz.R`: `.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) if ( ! "Github_pkg" %in% (all.available = TRUE)){devtools::install_github("myGithub/Github_pkg")}`. Do you think this is okay if I submit to CRAN? And if `drat` is preferrable, could you give me a little more guidance on how to insert my `Github_pkg` using `drat`? Many thanks!!